# Difference between g- and u

Tags: undo-redo

`g-` is *Return to older text state*, and `u` is *Undo change*.
I don't get it.

Comment: Read the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_undo_branches)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out vim's documentation on [undo branches](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#undo-branches). `u` is essentially going to take you back to the parent of the current node, whereas `g-` allows you to traverse the current node's siblings before traversing to the root of the branch. Each node represents a change in the file. The documentation's description is a bit obscure but that is how I understand it. You might find [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_undo_branches) explanation of undo branches to be easier to understand.

**Example Scenario**
I will use the following notation to explain the current structure of the undo tree:

[{parent} --> ({child}, {sibling})]

1. Open a text file. [**root**]
2. Make a change A. [root --> **A**]
3. Leave insert mode and make another change B. [root --> A --> **B**]
4. Undo B with the `u` key. [root --> **A** --> B]
5. Make a new change C. [root --> A --> (B, **C**)]

Pressing `u` at this point would take you back to change A. Pressing `g-`, on the other hand, would take you to change B.